# I completed a project but when I send the file in email when i attach the files the images do not appear how do i fix it it so they appear?

Tags: html-email, display, responsive-images

```css
  <style >

    em.quote{
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 515px;
      margin-left: 550px;

    }
    .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }}

 


  



  
   

   #main{

    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color:  #b48eaeff;

  }


  p.info{
    font-family: sans-serif; 
  }


  p.link{

    text-align: center;
  }
    
    #image{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 100%
    }
















  </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
 







     
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">



<html>
<head>
  



   
  
 
<div id="main">
  <h1 id="title"> Dr.Norman Borlaug</h1>
</div>

<div id="img-div"> 
  <div id="img-caption" alt=" A gallery of images of Norman Borlaug"> 
  <div class="row" class=“img-responsive”>
  <div class="column">
        <img src="img/normanwithpeople.png" alt="Norman Borlaug having a conversion with colleuges">
        <img src="img/norman-borlaug.png" alt="Norman Borlaug in a field smiling" id ="image">
        <img src="img/normanholdingnobelpize.png" alt=" Norman Borlaug holding the Nobel Peace Prize">
  
    </div>
     
    <div class="column">
         <img src="img/normanatconference.png" alt="Norman Borlaug at a confrence">
         <img src="img/normanwithjimmy.png" alt="Norman_Borlaug with  former President Jimmy Carter">
         <img src="img/normaninmexico.jpg"  alt=" A painting of Norman Borlaug in a field in Mexico">
    
  </div>

    <div class="column">
    <img src="img/norman.png" alt="Norman Borlaug and his wife">
    <img src="img/normangetsaward.png" alt="Norman Borlaug receives an award from president George W Bush">
    <img src="img/normanatscience.png" alt=" Norman Borlaug at a agricultural science and technology ">
  </div>
</div>

       
     


 
    
   <p class="important">

    <em class="quote">Fathered a revolution that saved billons of lives</em>
    
  </p>
</head>
 

    
 <div id="tribute-info">
   <p class="info">Norman Ernest Borlaug (March 25, 1914 – September 12, 2009) was an American agronomist who led initiatives worldwide that contributed to the extensive increases in agricultural production termed the Green Revolution. Borlaug was awarded multiple honors for his work, including the Nobel Peace Prize, the Presidential Medal of Freedom and the Congressional Gold Medal.

Borlaug received his B.S. in forestry in 1937 and Ph.D. in plant pathology and genetics from the University of Minnesota in 1942. He took up an agricultural research position with CIMMYT in Mexico, where he developed semi-dwarf, high-yield, disease-resistant wheat varieties. During the mid-20th century, Borlaug led the introduction of these high-yielding varieties combined with modern agricultural production techniques to Mexico, Pakistan, and India. As a result, Mexico became a net exporter of wheat by 1963. Between 1965 and 1970, wheat yields nearly doubled in Pakistan and India, greatly improving the food security in those nations.

Borlaug was often called "the father of the Green Revolution", and is credited with saving over a billion people worldwide from starvation. According to Jan Douglas, executive assistant to the president of the World Food Prize Foundation, the source of this number is Gregg Easterbrook's 1997 article "Forgotten Benefactor of Humanity." The article states that the "form of agriculture that Borlaug preaches may have prevented a billion deaths." He was awarded the Nobel Peace Prize in 1970 in recognition of his contributions to world peace through increasing food supply.</p></div>
  
</body>

  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug"  target="_blank" id="tribute-link"> <p class="link"> Learn More About Norman Borlaug<p>

    </html>
```

This the code for the project but how do I display the images so anyone can see currently can see it since i have the images in a folder together but nobody else can I sent as an attached file to a friend it popped up for the most part but the images don't display on mobile or when i forward it to someone else / to the public as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your images have a relative path--they need a full (absolute) path.

So change this: `src="img/normanwithpeople.png"`

To this: `src="https://www.server.com/path/to/img/normanwithpeople.png"`